# Expected application_type to be one of [web other java MobileCenter phone store ios Node.JS], got Web

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-application-insights, terraform-provider-azure

**Previous Terraform Version**: 0.13.0 
**AzureRM Version**: 2.13.0

**New Version Terraform**: 0.14.0 
**AzureRM Version**: 2.13.0

**Affected Resource(s)**: 
azurerm_application_insights

When we upgraded to version 0.14.0 of Terraform we get the following error:
"**Expected application_type to be one of [web other java MobileCenter phone store ios Node.JS], got Web.**"

We know it is case sensitive but our environment is already set "Web".

I read this issue since it was the same issue we are running into:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6259

We do have the following code set: but it seems to have no effect:
lifecycle {
ignore_changes = [
application_type
]
}

We still get the same error. This is blocking us. How can we resolve this issue?  Is there a way to change the "Web" to "web" to the existing application insights? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you simply change "Web" to "web" in the TF code?

Comment: Figured out the issue.  https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27097  We upgraded from 0.14.0 to 0.14.7.  This fixed it.  We are unblock now.  Thank you.

Comment: We had that already in the TF code.  The issue was with the existing environments that were already set with "Web".